# how do i add a page indicator like "Question 1 of 10"?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i add something like this to my quizzer [page indicator](https://www.w3schools.com/quiztest/quiztest.asp?qtest=HTML) I've been searching and trying for a couple of days i couldn't figure this out.

**total question**

```
<?php
    //total question
    $db = new db;
    $link = $db->dbconnect();
    $iauid = $_SESSION["uid"];
    $qizid = $_SESSION["qizid"];
    $qry = "SELECT COUNT qcatid FROM AS total FROM tbcat";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $qry) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['total'];
?>
<label id="numberIndicator">1</label>
<?php
```

**page indicator**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //page indicator
    function add() {
        var quantity_temp = document.getElementById("numberIndicator").innerText;
        var quantity_int = parseInt(quantity_temp, 10) + 1;
        document.getElementById("numberIndicator").innerHTML = quantity_int.toString();
    }
</script>
```

**it should be like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query looks wrong:

```php
$qry = "SELECT COUNT qcatid FROM AS total FROM tbcat";
```

Should be more like this (since COUNT is a function)

```php
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(qcatid) total FROM tbcat";
```

Well, the simplest way starting from the code you posted would be something like this (in your PHP):

```php
Question <label id="currentPageIndicator"><?=$currentPage?></label> of <label id="totalPageIndicator"><?=$row['total']?></label>
```

Where `$currentPage` would be assigned a default of 1 and would either be stored in session or would be calculated by current row selection from your query that fetches data or something in that direction.